# how to use coinhive java script with GPU?

Tags: mining, gpu-mining, javascript

i use coinhive simple UI miner and sometimes javascript miner for mining Monero in coinhive.com
can i use GPU instead of CPU for mining in coinhive website?

Comment: Currently all common JavaScript libraries have just implemented CPU computation in their mathematic algorithms. They are pretty much standardized on all major platforms.
GPUs are not that much standardized and just roughly implemented in JavaScript libraries, so I don't think you would gain much even if implementing a GPU driven JavaScript miner...

Comment: do anyone know how to help me ? I would like to mine on coinhive from a linux terminal.. kind regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coinhive runs on your CPU only. Although it's technically possible to write javascript code that runs on GPU it's not standard and it's not the approach taken by coinhive.

If you have GPUs there are better ways to use them for mining than coinhive, such as joining a mining pool.